# Algorithm Scripting: Sum All Odd Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

I am trying to solve this issue.

" Given a positive integer num , return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to num .

The first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 1 and 1. Every additional number in the sequence is the sum of the two previous numbers. The first six numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and 8.

For example, sumFibs(10) should return 10 because all odd Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to 10 are 1, 1, 3, and 5."

This was my solution, and I just can’t understand why it satisfies all the statements except the last one. I can’t find the mistake.
I would appreciate any help!

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  if(num === 1){
    return 1;
  }else if(num ===2){
    return 2;
  }

let arr=[1,1],
curr =1,
prev =1;

for(let i = 2; i<num;i++){
  let next = curr + prev;
  prev = curr;
  curr= next;
  
  if(curr<num && curr%2!==0){
      arr.push(curr);    
  }
}

   return arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
}

console.log(sumFibs(75024));
console.log(sumFibs(75025));
```

It's giving me the same result for both even when they should be different.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to add numbers that are "less or equal to num". You are summing only numbers < num.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake appears to be the conditional statement  `if(curr<num && curr%2!==0)` which does't satify the instructions above which say as follows:
***return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to num***

Therefore when we use   `if(curr<num && curr%2!==0)` as our conditional statement we do not include 75025 since it doesn't represent a number less than the variable num.

That is where we find the mistake. It should include numbers that are not only less but also the ones that are equal to ***num***, in this case ***num*** being 75025, which wasn't being include in the group of odd Fibonacci numbers to sum up, due to the incorrect conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are only considering numbers less than num, but the task description says less than or equal. The base case for 1 is also wrong. Actually you don't need the base cases at the beginning. And instead of the for loop you should use a while loop.